# Unable to select more than fist match jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery code that checks a attribute `data-tipo` on each `<th>` from a table, and depending of its content sets a specific value for each `<td>` in that column. See [example for better understanding](https://jsfiddle.net/yf49c2p5/).

JS:

```
  var tabla = $('table');

  tabla.find('tr th').each(function(i) {

    var tipo = $(this).data('tipo');

    if (tipo === 'string') {
      var celda = tabla.find('tr td').eq(i);
      celda.attr('data-valor', celda.text());
    }
    if (tipo === 'number') {
      var celda = tabla.find('tr td').eq(i);
      var numSaneado = celda.text().replace('.', '').replace(',', '.').replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
      celda.attr('data-valor', numSaneado);
    }
  });
```

It works fine, placing on every `<td>` from a column with a `data-tipo='string'` header the correct `data-value`, and the same with any `data-tipo='number'`, but as said it only does on the first row.

[image]

How to make this work on all rows?

Comment: Try using `table.find('tr').find('td').eq(i)` instead.  If ever possible, don't use `('tr td')` style selectors are they are very inefficient.  If that doesn't work, do `.find('tr').each(....)` and get your tds in the loop.

Comment: @nurdyguy: _"If ever possible, don't use ('tr td') style selectors are they are very inefficient"_ - irrelevant for most cases though.

Comment: `eq(i)` returns a single element. Sounds like you want to do `table.find('tr').each(function (tr) { var celda = $(tr).find('td').eq(i); ...`

Comment: @nurdyguy as far as I know that is right the sale as ('tr td'), anyway neither that works: same result

Comment: Thank you @MikeMcCaughan, based on your tip y made some changes that work properly. If you add it as an answer I'll tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the selector `"tr td"` you're combining the selection of the row and its cells. So, when you do `tabla.find('tr td').eq(i);`, it's only selecting the "`i`th" combination of row and cell.

Instead, I believe you want to find the `i`th cell in each row. To do that, select all of the rows, then find the correct cell in each one. Here's one way of doing that:

```
table.find('tr').each(function (tr) {
  var celda = $(tr).find('td').eq(i);
  // the rest of your code
});
```

That iterates through the rows, finding each `i`th cell in the row.